# How to perform replacements on a string only if it is not preceded and followed by a substring?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, replace, regex-group

```py
import re, datetime

input_text = "Alrededor de las 00:16 am o las 23:30 pm 2022_-_02_-_18 , quizas cerca del 2022_-_02_-_18 llega el avion, pero no (2022_-_02_-_18 20:16 pm) a las (2022_-_02_-_18 00:16 am), de esos hay dos (22)"

print(repr(input_text)) # --> output


input_date_structure = r"(?P<year>\d*)_-_(?P<month>\d{2})_-_(?P<startDay>\d{2})"

identify_only_date_regex_00 = input_date_structure + r"[\s|]*" + r"(\b\d{2}:\d{2}[\s|]*[ap]m)?" #to identify if there is a time after  the date
identify_only_date_regex_01 = r"(\b\d{2}:\d{2}[\s|]*[ap]m)?" + r"[\s|]*" + input_date_structure #to identify if there is a time before the date


date_restructuring_structure = r"\g<year>_-_\g<month>_-_\g<startDay>"
restructuring_only_date = lambda x: x.group() if x.group(1) else "(" + fr"{x.expand(date_restructuring_structure)}" + " 00:00 am)"

#do the replace with re.sub() method and the regex patterns instructions
input_text = re.sub(identify_only_date_regex_00, restructuring_only_date, input_text)
input_text = re.sub(identify_only_date_regex_01, restructuring_only_date, input_text)

#print output
print(repr(input_text)) # --> output
```

The **wrong output** that I get:

```
'Alrededor de las 00:16 am o las 23:30 pm 2022_-_02_-_18 , quizas cerca del(2022_-_02_-_18 00:00 am) llega el avion, pero no ((2022_-_02_-_18 00:00 am) 20:16 pm) a las ((2022_-_02_-_18 00:00 am) 00:16 am), de esos hay dos (22)'
```

The **correct output**, where only dates that were not preceded or followed by times **hh:mm am or pm**, indicated as `r"(\d{2}:\d{2}[ \s|]*[ap]m)?"`, are modified:

```
"Alrededor de las 00:16 am o las 23:30 pm 2022_-_02_-_18 , quizas cerca del (2022_-_02_-_18 00:00 am) llega el avion, pero no (2022_-_02_-_18 20:16 pm) a las (2022_-_02_-_18 00:16 am), de esos hay dos (22)"
```

I don't understand why it's failing, at least I think I'm conditioning my regex correctly using `\b` and `?`

Not replace
`"sdsdds 2022_-_02_-_18 00:16 am sdsddssd2`

Not replace
`"sdsdsd 00:16 am 2022_-_02_-_18 sdsdsd"`

replace
`"sdsdds 2022_-_02_-_18 sdsdsd"`

Comment: The `?` in `(group)?` makes the grouped expression optional, which means either of your two "identify_only_date..." expressions could potentially match every date with or without time. Your testing of `x.group() if x.group(1)` is probably not what you want, since captured group 1 is going to be different for both expressions; you could change all groups to named ones and test for `if x.group('name')` instead. You could alter your structure to something like `(?P<before>time)?(?P<year>...)(?P<after>time)?` and test for "before" and "after" in your lambda or you could use negative lookarounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can merge the two regexps to form an expression like `(Group1)?(...)(Group5)?` (`5` is due to the fact you have three capturing groups in the middle part, and even though they are named capturing groups, they are still assigned a numeric ID), and then check if Group 1 or 5 is matched inside the lambda:

```py
import re, datetime

input_text = "Alrededor de las 00:16 am o las 23:30 pm 2022_-_02_-_18 , quizas cerca del 2022_-_02_-_18 llega el avion, pero no (2022_-_02_-_18 20:16 pm) a las (2022_-_02_-_18 00:16 am), de esos hay dos (22)"

input_date_structure = r"(?P<year>\d*)_-_(?P<month>\d{2})_-_(?P<startDay>\d{2})"

identify_only_date_regex = r"(\b\d{2}:\d{2}[\s|]*[ap]m)?[\s|]*" + input_date_structure + r"[\s|]*(\b\d{2}:\d{2}[\s|]*[ap]m)?"

date_restructuring_structure = r"\g<year>_-_\g<month>_-_\g<startDay>"
restructuring_only_date = lambda x: x.group() if x.group(1) or x.group(5) else "(" + x.expand(date_restructuring_structure) + " 00:00 am)"

input_text = re.sub(identify_only_date_regex, restructuring_only_date, input_text)
print(repr(input_text)) # --> output
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/JE74Tn).

The output is

```
Alrededor de las 00:16 am o las 23:30 pm 2022_-_02_-_18 , quizas cerca del(2022_-_02_-_18 00:00 am)llega el avion, pero no (2022_-_02_-_18 20:16 pm) a las (2022_-_02_-_18 00:16 am), de esos hay dos (22)
```

Comment: thank you so much i didn't know you could do that